# Quickest way to search my code for a complex string in Netbeans?

Tags: regex, netbeans

I can search all files using CTRL-SHIFT-F. But I want to search specifically for a line that has the conditions:

- Contains "created"
- Contains "4PM" after that

So hits could include

- $bla['created'= '4pm';
- 'created this point at 4pm';

etc...

Is there a way to search using a type of wildcard like this: created*4pm ?

**UPDATE**

I see you can just use Regex in Netbeans. Now the tricky part is how to use REGEX in netbeans to search for strings that can find the above?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the command line. `cd` to the src folder and do a recursive `grep`.

`grep -R "MY_REGEX" *`

Depending on your regex use the appropriate switch, have a look at the output of:

```
grep --help | grep regex
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the following work:

```
created.*4pm
```